# scipy sparse matrix to cvxopt spmatrix?

Tags: scipy, sparse-matrix, cvxopt

I need to convert a scipy sparse matrix to cvxopt's sparse matrix format, spmatrix, and haven't come across anything yet (the matrix is too big to be converted to dense, of course). Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

The more robust answer is a combination of [hpaulj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25319978/3614835) and [OferHelman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28714624/3614835).

```
def scipy_sparse_to_spmatrix(A):
    coo = A.tocoo()
    SP = spmatrix(coo.data.tolist(), coo.row.tolist(), coo.col.tolist(), size=A.shape)
    return SP
```

Defining the shape variable preserves the dimensionality of A on SP. I found that any zero columns ending the scipy sparse matrix would be lost without this added step.

Answer (score 1):

taken from http://maggotroot.blogspot.co.il/2013/11/constrained-linear-least-squares-in.html

```
coo = A.tocoo()
SP = spmatrix(coo.data, coo.row.tolist(), coo.col.tolist())
```

Comment: You also need to call coo.data.tolist()

Answer (score 0):

From http://cvxopt.org/userguide/matrices.html#sparse-matrices

```
cvxopt.spmatrix(x, I, J[, size[, tc]])
```

looks similar to the `scipy.sparse`

```
coo_matrix((data, (i, j)), [shape=(M, N)])
```

My guess is that if `A` is a matrix in `coo` format, that

```
cvxopt.spmatrix(A.data, A.row, A.col, A.shape)
```

would work.  (I don't have `cvxopt` installed to test this.)