# Feeding scipy.sparse() sparse matrices into CVXOPT

Tags: python, scipy, cvxopt

[I'm following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35566620/189035)]

I am trying to feed sparse matrices in CVXOPT. Consider the following minimal example:

```
import numpy
import cvxopt
import scipy.sparse

K = 10
n = 36

g_0 = numpy.random.randn(n, K)
d_0 = numpy.zeros(n) + 1.0
g_2 = scipy.sparse.dia_matrix(([d_0], [0]), shape=(n, n))
g_3 = scipy.sparse.dia_matrix(([-d_0], [0]), shape=(n, n))
g_1 = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(g_0)
g_4 = scipy.sparse.hstack([g_1, g_2, g_3])

A   = cvxopt.spmatrix(g_4.data.tolist(), g_4.col.tolist(), g_4.row.tolist(), size = g_4.shape)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: dimension too small
```

Is this a bug or (more likely) am I misunderstanding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35566620/189035) answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just switched the row-column-order to column-row-order within your arguments during the matrix-creation call.

This is in conflict with the argument of size `g_4.shape`. Look at [cvxopt's docs](http://cvxopt.org/userguide/matrices.html#cvxopt.spmatrix). Size first treats, I (2nd arg), then J (3rd arg).

```
A   = cvxopt.spmatrix(g_4.data.tolist(), g_4.col.tolist(), g_4.row.tolist(), size = g_4.shape)  # wrong
A   = cvxopt.spmatrix(g_4.data.tolist(), g_4.row.tolist(), g_4.col.tolist(), size = g_4.shape)  # correct
```